# Running Skypekit as Service

Tags: c#, service, skype

I have developed a Gui-app that uses skypekit which works great. I know have the requirement to make it a service or as "service like" as possible.

I would need the skypekit.exe to run in some shape or form as a service. I was looking into wrapping the exe as a service , but I would need to wrap the gui and skypekit exe as one!.
I only found

http://gocoding.com/page.php?al=servicecontrol,http://gocoding.com/page.php?al=gensvc

Which did not work for.  I found a link on the skype fourm here:

http://devforum.skype.com/t5/SkypeKit-API/Windows-Skype-Runtime-as-Windows-Service/m-p/3782/highlight/true#M3306

But no success either.

What I would like to know is how I might go about making 2 exe's into 1 service: if that is possible how?, or any other techniques I might try to achieve the result. There is very little out there in the way of this I can find.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK to run Skype as a service you need to run it in a virtual machine or isolated desktop environment.

Here is one example:

https://sevabot-skype-bot.readthedocs.org/